# When extrapolating for projections, how do you know which function-form to use?

Tags: statistics, data-analysis, extrapolation

When you have a set of raw data, there are many models to extrapolate a projection. Linear, Quadratic, Logarithmic, Etc.

How does one know which to use? I'm assuming its by the nature of the data source itself but if that is unknown what is the best method?

---

For the sake of example and as a discussion point, we have [world GDP growth rate](https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/NY.GDP.MKTP.KD.ZG).

GDP growth rate is correlated to population growth rate I'd imagine which I believe is logarithmic, so therefor logarithmic model could be used for projections (granted there are other factors like life-span, automation, etc that could be considered and might not be of minimal impact). 
If this is the case is logarithmic a sufficient model, or does the exponential growth rate of automation need to be accounted for as well?

---

Additionally, what if the data set had been random and I had not known its source and therefor been able to correlate it to population growth and Fibonacci, is there a good set of standards for determining which projection model to use or is it up to interpretation?

I'm assuming one can look at the error-rate of how far a data point is from the extrapolated function and "rank" it then see which projection model had the minimal amount of error? But this might not always be best, especially with a low sample size.

Comment: It would be reasonable to say that you think GDP will follow an exponential projection for the reasons you give above.  But the GDP growth rate (i.e. $\frac {GDP_2}{GDP_1}$) use a linear growth rate.  When in doubt, use the simplest plausible model (usually that will be linear).

Comment: In general, it's difficult to determine which model to use without an underlying notion of how it should change. One way to do a guess-and-check is to use a subset of the data up to a certain time (say 1980-2000) to generate a model, and check it against the data after that time (2000-2017). Then you can pick a new subset of data from the same time, use a new model, and check again. This will let you test the predictive power of your model on known data. However, this is not fool-proof and may lead to overfitting. You can read more about K-fold cross-validation for more info.

Comment: @DougM That makes sense however it seems using a linear model, GDP growth rate would eventually become negative and go all the way to -∞ in ∞ years. Since GDP can't decline from the previous year (as far as I know) it seems it should instead asymptote towards 1. Asymptotes can't happen in linear so I'm self-urged to lean towards logarithmic at that point.

Comment: @AlexanderJ93 That's an interesting approach, good strategy, do you know an optimal time range; for example extrapolating only the first 75% of data points and comparing the projection to the final 25%. I'd imagine there could be an optimal `X%` for this type of approach? Perhaps Φ (0.6180339887)?

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw GDP can absolutely decline year over year.  However you are correct.  Constant growth is the simplest model.  The next choice is a step function.

Comment: @DougM Brain slip, you're right, I was thinking of world net-worth. (Though I suppose that can technically decline too due to entropy-type destruction)